# Invalid column name 'QuestionGroup_QuestionGroupID'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a .NET, MVC 5, EF 6 Code First project.  Basically, on saving an object to the database with EF, I'm getting `{"Invalid column name 'QuestionGroup_QuestionGroupID'."}`.  `QuestionGroup` is the model, and it has relationships with child models which have foreign keys `QuestionGroupID`.  The name of its key is `QuestionGroupID`, both in the model and its corresponding table.

The model:

```
public class QuestionGroup
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Int32 QuestionGroupID { get; set; }
    //Other properties omitted for brevity

    public Guid MasteryObjectiveID { get; set; }
    public virtual MasteryObjective MasteryObjective {
        //Necessary because this model is in a different context/db and EF doesn't support that.
        get { return DAL.DatabaseMethods.GetMasteryObjective(MasteryObjectiveID); }
    }
    public virtual List<MultipleChoiceQuestion> Questions{ get; set; }
}
```

The `MasteryObjective` doesn't have a foreign key to `QuestionGroup` because it's a many-to-one relationship from QuestionGroups to MasteryObjectives.  The Question models are shown below:

```
public abstract class Question
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Int32 QuestionID { get; set; }
    //Other properties omitted for brevity

    public Int32 QuestionGroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }
}

//Use this attribute whenever inheriting from an abstract class so EF will create separate tables for each.
[Table("MultipleChoiceQuestion")]
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question
{
    public List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

The outer exception I get is `DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code` and the inner exception is `Invalid column name 'QuestionGroup_QuestionGroupID'.`.

The error is being thrown from where a database method saves it like

```
context.QuestionGroup.Add(qg); context.SaveChanges();
```

This method hasn't changed for quite a while and I'm pretty certain there's nothing wrong there.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The column may not exist in the database. If you're using migrations, try running `update-database` from the package manager.

It may help to browse the database as well, verifying that it is named correctly. If it's something else, you can decorate the key like so:

```
[Key]
[Required]
[Column("QuestionGroupID")] // Change this to whatever the column is named
public Int32 QuestionGroupID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Like I said, the column is named correctly in the database table; already checked that.